# Ways to avoid using text in raphael?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, raphael

I have recently been working a lot with the text feature of raphael, and I have been having a huge number of issues.

My application requires the text to be loaded into draggable, zoomable raphael sets. Unfortunately the text from,

```
var title = paper.text(0,0,"this is text");
...
mySet.push(title);
...
mySet.animate({scale: ".5 .5 0 0"},1000,function(){...})
```

does not scale the text along with with the set.

I tried a number of different approaches to attack this problem, including paper.print(), and have had nothing but issues.

I am thinking at this point, it would make lots more sense to dynamically generate an HTML5-canvas to properly display all of the text and information I need, then move the canvas into an image that can be inserted into my raphael project.

**Does anyone know of any alternative solutions, or how i might go about creating a canvas, and pulling the image of this canvas into my raphael project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using HTML5 worked out great.

I did the following:

```
var canvas = jQuery("<canvas width=300px height=400px />");
var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

context.font = "10pt Calibri ";
context.textAlign = "left";
context.textBaseline = "top";

context.fillText("this is text", xPos, yPos);
```

and then to implement it in my raphael set, i did:

```
var img = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png"); //turns the canvas object into a png and returns the dynamic url 
var bb = mySet.getBBox();
mySet.push(
  paper.image(img,bb.x,bb.y,300,400)
)
```

Comment: This is a possibly very useful integration tip because text quality in native Raphael is inconsistent